# How do I make sure I am not recreating multiple DB connections in PHP class?

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I am not real good at this yet and I have tried to figure it out but can't seem to do so.

I am trying to write a PHP class which reuses its database connection and doesn't make a new one every time it needs it. How do I make sure I am not recreating a new connection every time?

Please consider the code below and let me know if I am creating several connections or reusing the same one in the PHP file.

Thanks

### PHP File

```
require_once(class.myclass.php);

$object = new myclass;

[...modify $object properties...]

if ($object->save_to_db()) {
  echo "OK \n";
}
else {
  echo "FAIL :" . $object->get_err();
}

[...modify $object properties...]

if ($object->save_to_db()) {
  echo "OK \n";
}
else {
  echo "FAIL :" . $object->get_err();
}

unset($object);
```

### Class file

```
class myclass {

    private $id;
    private $db;                        // Database Connection
    private $err;                       // Error

    public function save_to_db() {

        $db = $this->get_db();

        $query = "...";

        if(!$db->execute($query)) {     
            $this->err = $db->get_err();
            $save_to_db = false;
        }
        else {
            $save_to_db = true;
        }

        unset($db);
        return $save_to_db;
    }

    private function get_db() {
        if (!isset($this->db)) {
            $this->db = new db;
        }
        return $this->db;
    }

    public function get_err() {
        return $this->err;
    }

    function __destruct() {
        if (isset($this->db)) {
          unset($this->db);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: mysql will recycle a connection if it already exists with the same credentials

Comment: So wait does that mean I don't need to bother with all this stuff above?

Comment: I think what he's saying is if you go through all this creating a new db object, if it has the same credentials it will just use the old one already in memory, so it will not make a new one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A really good way to create a database handler is to use a static class method which returns itself. Called a Singleton pattern.

```
class DB {

  /**
   * Points to the instance of this class.
   * @var object
   */
  private static $instance = null;

  /**
   * Points to the database connection
   * @var object
   */
  private $db;

  /**
   * Initiates a new instance of self if one isn't set and opens a db connection
   * @return object an object of self
   */
  public static function getInstance() {
    if(self::$instance == null) {
      self::$instance = new self;
      $this->db = new PDO();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  /**
   * Runs a query on the database
   * @param  string $query the query to run on the db
   * @return array         the result set
   */
  public function query($query) {
    // Query..
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
}
```

And the simple usage would be:

```
$result = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM table");
var_dump($result); // Outputs array of results.
```

This will only open one connection the first time you invoke DB::getInstance(). This way, you don't have to initiate the class and it supports chaining. This method is used by the Laravel framework aswell.

There are various ways of doing this, as lxg stated, the singleton method is one way of doing it, but you can also assign the class the connection which you open at the start of the scripts runtime.

```
class NeedDB {

  /**
   * Points to the DB connection
   * @var object
   */
  private $db;

  /**
   * Class constructor
   * @param object $db The DB connection object
   */
  public function __construct($db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  /**
   * Runs a query on the database
   * @param  string $query the query
   * @return array         the result set
   */
  public function query($query) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
}

$db = new PDO();
$class = new NeedDB($db);

$result = $class->query("SELECT * FROM table");
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks! I like that last method.

Answer (score -1):

There are several approaches to this. Generally, when creating a “real-world” application, you would use a decent framework which provides the database connection and common DB features as a dependency/service.

But while you're playing, these are the most common for a simple use case:

A) The [Singleton](http://coderoncode.com/2014/01/27/design-patterns-php-singletons.html) design pattern. (Using singletons is discouraged these days in favour of dependency injection, but for the sake of playing/learning, it's acceptable to use it.)

B) Assign the DB connection to a global variable (i.e. outside the context of any function) and import it, when you need it, with the `global` keyword. This would look something like this:

```php
$db = createMyConnection();

function iNeedTheDbConnection() 
{
    global $db;
    // here goes the code that uses the connection
}
```

This is actually even worse than the singleton, but it works, and is still widely used (e.g. in WordPress).